# Inject object in injected service class using Mockito

Tags: java, logging, junit, dependency-injection, mockito

I'm trying to write a a JUnit test for a service in our JavaEE7 application.
The service class under test injects another service class which in turn injects yet another class.
Here's my classes in short:

```
class ServiceA {
   ServiceB serviceB;
   public void methodA() {
     serviceB.methodB();
   }
}

class ServiceB {
   @Inject
   ServiceC serviceC;
   public void methodB() {
      serviceC.methodC();
   }
}

class ServiceC {
   public void methodC() {}
}

class TestServiceA {
   @Spy
   ServiceA serviceA;
   @InjectMocks
   ServiceB serviceB;
   @Before
   public void setUp() {
      serviceA.serviceB = mock(ServiceB.class);
   }

   @Test
   public void testServiceA() {
      serviceA.methodA();
   }
}
```

EDIT: Edited from original Logger question to general object question.
The question is if it is possible or necessary to inject multiple levels of objects in my tests or if I should just mock the first injected service and capture all method calls to subsequent service with when-Expressions?

Comment: The first question would be, why do you need to inject the logger instead of simply asking the LoggerFactory for it? And why is it ok to  call `serviceA.serviceB = ...` in your test - but not `serviceB.log = ...`? It's not quite clear what you are asking... Mockito is for mocking, do you want to mock the logger? Or do you want the injection logic for a real logger?

Comment: Actually the example is not restricted to injecting the Logger. I have changed the Logger to be created using the LoggerFactory instead of injecting it and now I have come to a point where I inject another serviceC in serviceB and my mockito test fails. But this is probably the time when I need to use a when-Expression in my test to mock the call to serviceC.

Comment: One reason for injecting the Logger is that we might want to use different Loggers in our application. We saw an example in the Book "Java EE 7 Workshop" where the authors listed a "TechLogger" and another logger for a different purpose. Not sure if this makes sense at all.

Comment: For the logging: You are using slf4j, iirc, so you don't need that. It's a logging facade that can be configured to use different loggers anyway, no need to do that in your code. Just use the slf4j api, including getting loggers from the factory and you'll be fine. The rest is just configuring slf4j.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aim to test for instance that methodB is really called when you use *serviceA.methodA()*.

The following code does this:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class ServiceA {

    @Inject
    ServiceB serviceB;

    public void methodA() {
        serviceB.methodB();
    }
}

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class ServiceB {

    @Inject
    Logger log;

    public void methodB() {
        log.debug("log message");
    }
}

import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.slf4j.Logger;

public class ServiceTest {

    /**
     * Create an instance of the class ServiceA.
     */
    @InjectMocks
    private ServiceA serviceA;

    /**
     * Create a fake instance of ServiceB.
     */
    @Mock
    private ServiceB serviceB;

    /**
     * Create a fake instance of Logger.
     */
    @Mock
    private Logger log;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    /**
     * Verify that methodB is called.
     */
    @Test
    public void testServiceA() {
        serviceA.methodA();
        verify(serviceB, times(1)).methodB();
    }
}
```

Here, the Logger must be a mock too, otherwise you will get a NPE.

Comment: When i am trying to mock Interface instead of Class it gives me NPE. for your example. instead of Logger i am using IMyInterface. Can you please suggest it.